# got error on AES algo for encrypting moving image

Tags: matlab, encryption, cryptography, steganography

I encrypted a gif image from simple **AES algo**. I got the final result from this algo in a hexa number. I didn't understand we know in a gif image has a number of frame, there is no use of frames in **AES algo** means did i get right result. Now can i use this result for embedding?

Comment: I think you need to find out the details of the encryption you are trying to match - these will tell you how to deal with multi-frame images.

Comment: i have a image which have 23 frames and video which have 840 frames after image encryption i got only hexa number for encrytion i don't need to use image frame for encrytion but right now i want to embed it by frame.What should i do?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are trying to embed a .gif in a video? Why do you need to encrypt it? You have a number; is this a checksum, or the decryption key?

Comment: Actually in my project I am using steganography and cryptography both  firstly I have to secure my image by AES algo then embed it with video

Comment: If you have an error please show the code and the entire stack trace. Read the FAQ on how to ask good questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES algorithms - in any mode - are designed to encrypt binary data. The output is binary data as well, although the implementation may choose to convert that to any format. That your GIF is multi-layer is of no consequence to the AES algorithm - as long as it is fed binary data it will encrypt.

Decryption works the same way. Unless you are taking the GIF apart, the entire image will be encrypted/decrypted - including any layers.

Steganography is hiding data in - for instance - an image. This is not the same as just performing the AES block cipher. Normally you cannot just encrypt an image and include that - the encrypted image is just random data - if you try and read a GIF format from just random data it is likely that your GIF parsing will fail.